# How do I set up Valgrind to search through all command line option permutations?

Tags: c, testing, valgrind

I would like to add Valgrind to my automated test suite, but as I understand it, Valgrind only tests the target binary according to the options that I supply for said binary. For instance, if I run:

```bash
valgrind --leak-check=yes ./target_bin -option1 option_arg
```

Valgrind will catch memory leaks in functions called when `option1` is invoked; but if I run the same command with `option2` instead of `option1`, different functions are invoked and Valgrind will analyze those instead.

If I am going to add Valgrind to an automated test suite, do I need to write a bash script with every single permutation of my program's options, such as:

```bash
valgrind --leak-check=yes ./target_bin -option1 option_arg
valgrind --leak-check=yes ./target_bin -option2 option_arg
valgrind --leak-check=yes ./target_bin -option3 option_arg -option4
```

Or am I missing something super obvious in the [Valgrind documentation](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual.html)? If the above solution *is* the correct answer, are there any ways of tracking these kinds of permutations? Because I can see this script getting very large very quickly

Comment: How are you going to test each of those options without Valgrind?  You're going to have to run the program 3 times for 3 options.  Use a variable `VALGRIND="valgrind --leak-check=yes --"` and then write `$VALGRIND ./target_bin -option1 option_arg` etc.  You could even use a loop to iterate over the options if the options and arguments do not contain spaces.  If they do contain spaces, that's a lot harder to automate.

Comment: Unit testing with Check. Every time my code is compiled it runs a test suite on most functions. There's very little manual testing involved.

Comment: OK — so just arrange for the Unit testing to invoke Valgrind appropriately when it runs each test.  More or less as in the accepted answer.  I'd make the Valgrind command more configurable, but that's a detail — the overall answer is firmly on the right tracks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valgrind does not support this functionality because it's much easier to implement in shell scripts. You could do something like

```
for args in \
    '-option1 option_arg' \
    '-option2 option_arg' \
    '-option3 option_arg -option4'; do
  valgrind --leak-check=yes ./target_bin $args
done
```